# Will the Gigabyte GT640 run 3 vga monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

Spotted one of these going quite cheap: http://uk.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4255

[image: Back of card]

It has two DVI outs, one VGA and a HDMI. I've found it it's locked to 3 simulations outs.

Been doing some research on DVI and am a little confused by the lack of clear specs on the card, I know there are dedicated pins for analogue video but am wondering if they will be actually hooked up as there is already a VGA port (ie. so I can use adaptors to get VGA).

My use case is hooking up two projectors and a monitor each running as an independent screen. The screen could be DVI but the projectors must be VGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work.

From the page you linked to:

> Dual link Dual Link DVI-**D***2 / D-Sub / HDMI with HDCP protection

And from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface):

> DVI-D (**digital only**, single-link or dual-link)

D-Sub (aka VGA) is not digital. It will not work without an active convertor.

Here is a picture with nice generic information which should be useful:

[image: Image of a DVI connector with parts highlighted]

Notice the analog connectors (4 pins and one bar) at the left. If those are present and hooked up then you have an ancient analog signal. In your case these are not even present on the card (zoom in on the you provided, you will notice that the four analog pins are missing, which confirms the specs).

Comment: Any suggestions for a budget card that could give three VGA outs?

Comment: Sadly no. I see plenty of budget cards with 2 analog VGA out. Some with DVI-I out where you **might** be able to use both analog from DVI-I and the VGA card. But no budget cards with 3 analog outs. ( unless you consider VisionTeks 5770 quad VGA card to be a budget card. For me it is not). And I am reluctant to list specific cards on SU since this is information which quickly gets out of date.